# Multiple values in one parameter field in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is there a way to use a parameter query to search for multiple values in text format in the same field? Ideally the parameter box would pop up and I can put in any number of values separate by commas.For example i would be putting in values like CAR1074,19-2140-4-0001 from the field 'CPN' in the parameter box. I tried the below query but it did not come up with any result. (Got a blank result sheet)

```
PARAMETERS [Enter CPN/M&E] Text (255);

SELECT PROD_SUPLR_MGMT_SNBX_DB_CUSTOMS_DATABASE.CPN,
       PROD_SUPLR_MGMT_SNBX_DB_CUSTOMS_DATABASE.MPN,
       PROD_SUPLR_MGMT_SNBX_DB_CUSTOMS_DATABASE.KEYWORD,
       PROD_SUPLR_MGMT_SNBX_DB_CUSTOMS_DATABASE.[PO NUMBER],
       PROD_SUPLR_MGMT_SNBX_DB_CUSTOMS_DATABASE.[PO LINE NUMBER],
       PROD_SUPLR_MGMT_SNBX_DB_CUSTOMS_DATABASE.[PO RECEIVED DATE],
       PROD_SUPLR_MGMT_SNBX_DB_CUSTOMS_DATABASE.[PO SUPPLIER CODE],
       PROD_SUPLR_MGMT_SNBX_DB_CUSTOMS_DATABASE.[PO SUPPLIER NAME],
       PROD_SUPLR_MGMT_SNBX_DB_CUSTOMS_DATABASE.[PO RECEIPT STATION],
       PROD_SUPLR_MGMT_SNBX_DB_CUSTOMS_DATABASE.[PO SYSTEM],
       PROD_SUPLR_MGMT_SNBX_DB_CUSTOMS_DATABASE.[RO NUMBER],
       PROD_SUPLR_MGMT_SNBX_DB_CUSTOMS_DATABASE.[RO LINE NUMBER],
       PROD_SUPLR_MGMT_SNBX_DB_CUSTOMS_DATABASE.[RO RECEIVED DATE],
       PROD_SUPLR_MGMT_SNBX_DB_CUSTOMS_DATABASE.[RO SUPPLIER CODE],
       PROD_SUPLR_MGMT_SNBX_DB_CUSTOMS_DATABASE.[RO SUPPLIER NAME],
       PROD_SUPLR_MGMT_SNBX_DB_CUSTOMS_DATABASE.[RO RECEIPT STATION],
       PROD_SUPLR_MGMT_SNBX_DB_CUSTOMS_DATABASE.[RO SYSTEM]
FROM PROD_SUPLR_MGMT_SNBX_DB_CUSTOMS_DATABASE
WHERE (((PROD_SUPLR_MGMT_SNBX_DB_CUSTOMS_DATABASE.CPN)=Instr("," & [CPN] & ",","," & [CPN] & ",")));
```

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you're trying to do (e.g. example input and example output). Currently, you're passing the same argument to both parameters of your `InStr`, making it always return 1, and you're using your `[Enter CPN/M&E]` parameter nowhere.

Comment: Example input:Entering multiple values like CAR1074,19-2140-4-0001 in the parameter query prompt. Output would be returning all the relevant columns mentioned in the query for the multiple vales entered.i tried replacing 'CPN' with the parameter Enter 'CPN/M&E' but still it did not come up with any result

Comment: Why are those CPN values so different? What do you mean by 'returning all the relevant columns'? The same columns will always return, it is the records returned that will change.

Comment: As far the CPN values are concerned, it is different because the data is obtained from multiple data sources. It is all in the text format though. Yes you are right,  the same columns will always return every time but the records retuned would change. sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

So search for the CPN within the input string and if found the position is greater than 0.

`WHERE InStr([Enter CPN/M&E, separate multiple values by comma], [CPN])>0`

Comment: I added this in the where statement WHERE ( ( (PROD_SUPLR_MGMT_SNBX_DB_CUSTOMS_DATABASE.CPN)=InStr([Enter CPN/M&E, separate multiple values by comma], [CPN]) ) )>0; Still no result just an empty result sheet with all columns

Comment: Well, that is not the suggestion. Did you try what I suggested?